# Why Orochimaru's Edo tensei gives summons white eye but the recent edo tensei has the black eye?

Tags: naruto

I'm just wondering why the first and the second has white eyes and their faces are clean no cracks?

Comment: In the original Naruto he(Orochimatu) used 2 dead bodies which he then modified with a special scroll(showed in the fight between the hokages) to revive them ( the 2 Hokage) and that is why they looked like that(clean,white eyeballs and with no cracks) .In Shipuuden he didn't use dead bodies and they are just artificial cells. It is just a presumption without any supporting research done prior to writing, just an affirmation done with the knowdeledge gained from watching the anime. Thus I can't formulate this as an answer, only as a comment hoping that someone will provide a concludent answer.

Comment: but Kabuto did the same technique with bodies as well if I'm not mistaken but it has black eye and crack faces.

Comment: Well as i said I don't have the proper knowdeledge to answer cause i have not seen the whole anime only some big parts so I am pretty inaccurate so i don't really know. Sorry 'bout that

Comment: I think it is 1 one of flaws of the writer. I was like bored and watching some of the big scenes of naruto the fight between orochimaru and the 3rd and 1 thing I also notice that the third coffin that he summoned from the technique edo tensei was stopped by the 3rd so Im thinking whos in the 3rd coffin? then theres a kanji on the coffin says 4th but that cant be Yondaime I believe his soul was sealed inside of the reaper. hmmm hehe well thanks anyway for your answer! :)

Comment: You are welcome! But i really hope someone will provide a documented answer to your question because i just expressed my opinion (i am not really documented in the Naruto universe) so it doesn't count as an answer.Glad to help you even  if just a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

When Orochimaru used that jutsu against 3rd Hokage, he hasn't mastered it yet, which is why both 1st Hokare and 2nd Hokage were that weak. With weak I mean they were not revived with all their power available for them to use.

Later, Kabuto mastered the jutsu, thus enabling him to summon the dead with all their power available for them to use. It seems that this also makes their appearance change quite a bit like you noted, in that they have different eye color and cracks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same thing with Izanagi, Kishimoto didn't think of the future while writing/drawing the earlier Manga, so it's just get retconned.

Here are comparison:
[image: First and Last Edo Tensei]

The first two looks like an emotionless, pale, living corpse. But in far-fat later episodes/chapters, edo tensei are just living corpse that has black eyeballs and can express emotions (you can see when the 'fail' edo tensei reacts to their acquaintance, they talk just like human beings. they also can allert their friend-now-enemy about the danger that will come).

I think it's just the way they differentiate living human and reanimated ones, in case there's a new audience/reader.